# in a multi-language site, why would I store some text strings in a database and write other one into the markup?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, internationalization, multilingual

I'm working on an existing multi-language site (Coldfusion/MySQL).

Why is it that on a lot of pages I'm sitting on, some text strings are always *hard-coded* into the markup like:

```
 <CFIF language = "EN"><p>Hello World</p></CFIF>
```

while others use the database to update text like so:

```
 <p><cfoutput>#tx_greetings#</cfoutput></p>
```

What is the best practice here? I thought if I'm going to use a database for translations, it would be easier to store all texts in there (long and small). If I'm not using a database, then all texts should be *if-elsed*. Mixing it is a little maintenance-heavy, isn't it?

Also, is there a limit on text-string-length, which I'm storing to MySQL? Maybe performance-wise?

Thanks for some inputs!

Comment: You might just have inherited a bit of developer lazyness. ("Can't be bothered to do the proper strings right now, get it working first and then, in the remaining time (ha!), refactor the strings into the proper I18n mechanics.")

Comment: I assume... do you have a link to get me started on l18n?

Comment: @freqent: not so much in a generic context, no. But I'd say the "everything in DB" approach is the more proper one, even if it is more bothersome (find new ID, check if existing message can be reused,...).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz. agree. Hacking away... Thanks for your insight. If you want to make it answer, I'll check. Grüße.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't store strings/translations in your code, that's bad practice if you want a maintainable i18n'd site.

You should store all your string in the same location, db or a properties file per language. It doesn't matter which, but be consistent. Personally I prefer a properties file as its easy to edit.

```
welcome_message=Hi {0}, Welcome to my site
```

Load all your translations in one go in onApplicationStart(), then provide a wrapper class to access them and to format the string with supplied arguments

for example

```
#i18n.getString(user.getLocale(), "welcome_message", [user.getUsername()])#
```

You can use java.text.MessageFormat[1] to provide powerful formatting

```
function getString(string locale, string key, array args) {
  var mf = createobject("java", "java.text.MessageFormat");
  mf.init(variables.strings[arguments.locale][arguments.key]);
  return mf.format(javacast("java.lang.Object[]", args));
}
```

The above is just an example, and you need to provide error catching and caching to this

Hope that helps point you in a productive direction

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/MessageFormat.html

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much. Delving into this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DB or a ascii file, depends on which you prefer. 
If u use a DB you can create a table with the following columns:

**country_code**    : country code for the language (*i.e. US for english*)

**definition_name** : name of the definition or message (*i.e. db_error_msg for a generic error message for db action*)

**definition value**    : value of the definition (*i.e. Sorry, an error occurred saving your data*)

Each record will be a definition.

Depending on the language the user select your app will filter the database and you will get a query of all definitions you need.
I usually use that query to set a session variable structure like:

```
   <cfif IsDefined("session.language") IS FALSE>
     <cfquery name="getDefinition" datasource="dsn">
     SELECT * FROM tbl_definitions WHERE country_code = "US"
     </cfquery>
     <cfset session.language = structnew()>
     <cfoutput query="getDefinitions">
       <cfset session.language["#definition_name#"] = "#definition_value#">
     </cfoutput>
  </cfif>
```

In the code I will simply use:

```
<cfoutput>
<h2>#session.language.db_error_msg#</h2>
</cfoutput>
```

and I will get the right message for the current language.
You can also use a master definition db to be used by different websites.

Same solution can be used with different configuration files (ie US.cfg. EN.cfg, ES.cfg) where  you set your definitions in simple way to get a list.
I usually use the following system:
definition_name = definition_value for each line

```
db_error_msg = Sorry, an error occured saving your data
db_success_msg = Record saved
```

Then I read the current language configuration file (i.e. US.cfg for english, ES.cfg for spanish) and get the same result

```
<cfif IsDefined("session.language") IS FALSE>
   <cffile action="read" file="#path#\US.cfg" variable="definitions">

   <cfset session.language = structnew()>
   <cfloop index="i" list="#definitions#" delimiters="#chr(10)#">
     <cfset definition_name = ListGetAt(i,1,"=")>
     <cfset definition_value = ListGetAt(i,2,"=")>
     <cfoutput>
        <cfset session.language["#definition_name#"] = "#definition_value#">
     </cfoutput>
   <cfloop>
</cfif>
```

This can be done just when session starts (if you know the language you need) and in both ways your definitions will be available everywhere inside your application for the user session time duration you have defined.
You can use definitions for buttons, messages, table headers, etc. creating a multilanguage ui in a very fast way without creating localized templates or using inline translations.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Great explanation. I have more or less set something like this up. Good to see I'm on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Just as some generic localization advice, be careful about the variable name you'll use to know which phrase to retrieve.  Don't just make it the english phrase, but make it something that is clearly a specific variable because you'll also have to handle contextual phrases that seem the same in English, but are very different in other languages depending on context.